# Convert the date time stamp to local epoch datatime

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime

Assume this is my date time stamp list:

```
[datetime.datetime(2017, 11, 17, 9, 33, 11), datetime.datetime(2017, 11, 17, 9, 33, 36), datetime.datetime(2017, 11, 17, 9, 33, 48)]
```

A lot of examples have been given for converting these values to epoch, but the values are in GMT.
How do we convert it to Epoch Local time?

To put it in simpler words. The general epoch conversion coverts the given date into epoch considering that the datetime given is in GMT. But the given date time is localtime!

Comment: Can you specify what you mean with epoch?

Comment: use `strftime('%s')`

Comment: Take the data 2017-11-7 09:33:11. The epoch value is 1510911191. Now, convert the Epoch to DateTime Stamp again and 

GMT is 2017-11-7 09:33:11
While, my local time for this epoch is 2017 3:03:11 PM. 

I want the local time and not GMT

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> x = datetime.datetime(2017, 11, 17, 9, 33, 36)
>>> x.timestamp()
1510882416.0
>>> x.ctime()
'Fri Nov 17 09:33:36 2017'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
l = [datetime.datetime(2017, 11, 17, 9, 33, 11), datetime.datetime(2017, 11, 17, 9, 33, 36), datetime.datetime(2017, 11, 17, 9, 33, 48)]

epo = [x.strftime('%s') for x in l]

print(epo)
# ['1510898591', '1510898616', '1510898628']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try [arrow](https://arrow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) lib:

```
import arrow
import datetime

x = datetime.datetime(2017, 11, 17, 9, 33, 36)
time = arrow.get(x, 'local').shift(hours=-6)  // here you can change hours to what you want 

print time 
>>2017-11-17T03:33:36+00:00

time = time.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')
print time
>>2017-11-17 03:33:36
```